# Hexadecimal, Bitwise OR reversal for TCP Flag Filter

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, bitwise-operators, pcap

I'm working with the TCP Dump packet capture method in C and I'm looking at the TCP flags section and I need a way to check if the SYN flag is set on a packet.

When I run the program I can get access to the `th_flags` variable which is inside the struct below, and i get a value like 6144 or 4096 in return. How do I figure out which flags are set based on the numbers it gives as output?

```
struct sniff_tcp {
    u_short th_sport;               /* source port */
    u_short th_dport;               /* destination port */
    tcp_seq th_seq;                 /* sequence number */
    tcp_seq th_ack;                 /* acknowledgement number */
    u_char  th_offx2;               /* data offset, rsvd */
    #define TH_OFF(th)      (((th)->th_offx2 & 0xf0) >> 4)
    u_char  th_flags;
    #define TH_FIN  0x01
    #define TH_SYN  0x02
    #define TH_RST  0x04
    #define TH_PUSH 0x08
    #define TH_ACK  0x10
    #define TH_URG  0x20
    #define TH_ECE  0x40
    #define TH_CWR  0x80
    #define TH_FLAGS        (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG|TH_ECE|TH_CWR)
    u_short th_win;                 /* window */
    u_short th_sum;                 /* checksum */
    u_short th_urp;                 /* urgent pointer */
};
```

I need to be able to test for various flags using the format `if (SYN is set) {...}`.

If i want to access the destination port variable I do this:

```
printf("   Dst port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_dport));
```

Thanks

Comment: Nesting `#define`s inside a `struct` definition is .... odd ... confusing ... difficult to read ... In any case, have you tried `if (some_packet.th_flags & TH_SYN) ...`? That would seem to be a good place to start...

Comment: @twalberg printf("   Dst port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_dport)); is how I access the other variable, how would I do that for the flags? (i didn't write the code + am more of a java person :p)

Comment: 1) You don't need `ntohs()` for single-byte variables like `th_flags`, although it doesn't really hurt anything, either; 2) `(tcp -> th_port) & TH_SYN`...

Comment: `(tcp -> th_flags) & TH_SYN`, that is... proofreading failure...

Comment: @twalberg Spotted that :p it's working now tyvm, although it doesn't seem to work for multiple flags (tcp -> th_flags) & TH_SYN & TH_ACK or (tcp -> th_flags) & (TH_SYN + TH_ACK)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (tcp ->th_flags & TH_SYN) 
{
  //TH_SYN is set
}
```